# Delphi 7, The handle is invalid, when moving cursor on the form :)

Tags: delphi, gdi

Here is small snippet of the code (ready to paste and run) which run one thread.
This thread get a list of the jpg files on disc, then do certain operations on it.

Normally it works okay. If I start moving the cursor on the form I get this error everytime :)

Any Idea?
Thanks!

```
unit uTest;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, jpeg, gr32;

type
  TThreadSafeJpegImage = class(TJPEGImage)
  protected
    procedure Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private    
  public    
  end;

  TWatek = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute;override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  thr: TWatek;
begin
  thr := TWatek.Create(true);
  thr.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  thr.Resume;
end;

{ TWatek }

procedure TWatek.Execute;
var
  sciezka: string;
  Rec : TSearchRec;
  Path : string;
  I: Integer;

  function TestFile(path: string): WideString;
  var
    stream: TMemoryStream;
    jpg: TThreadSafeJpegImage;
    bmp32: TBitmap32;
    strStr: TStringStream;
    err: String;
  begin
    try
      stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      jpg := TThreadSafeJpegImage.Create;

      try
        stream.LoadFromFile(path);
        jpg.LoadFromStream(stream);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(stream);
      end;

      bmp32 := TBitmap32.Create;
      try
        bmp32.Assign(jpg);
        strStr := TStringStream.Create('');
        bmp32.SaveToStream(strStr);
        strStr.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(jpg);
        FreeAndNil(bmp32);
      end;

      result := strStr.DataString;
      FreeAndNil(strStr);
    except
      on e: exception do
      begin
        err := e.Message;
        showmessage (err);
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  sciezka := 'd:\pictures\';

  for I := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    Path := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(sciezka) ;
    if FindFirst (Path + '*.jpg', faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
    begin
      try
        repeat
          TestFile (Path + Rec.Name);
        until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
      finally
        FindClose(Rec) ;
      end;
    end;
  end;

end;

{ TThreadSafeJpegImage }

procedure TThreadSafeJpegImage.Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect);
begin
  Bitmap.Canvas.Lock;
  try
    inherited Draw(ACanvas, Rect);
  finally
    Bitmap.Canvas.Unlock;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? The debugger should interrupt and show you the line that threw the exception. Start your investigation there.

Comment: An error is on this line: bmp32.SaveToStream(strStr);
The problem is I have no idea why moving the cursor on the form affects my thread

Comment: That line isn't the problem. The problem is deeper. Turn on the "debug DCUs" option in your project's linker settings and try again. You're looking for the line of code that calls `raise`. When you find it in the debugger, look at the "call stack" window to find out how your program got there.

Comment: No problem here with the code above. (also D7)

Comment: This error is raised in GDIError procedure of a Graphics unit

Comment: NGLN: Have you been moving the cursor over the form when the thread has been active?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy
00472d2c +07c Project.exe Graphics   2619  +4 GDIError
00472d6b +00f Project.exe Graphics   2626  +1 GDICheck
004790de +132 Project.exe Graphics   6339 +30 TBitmap.WriteStream
00479300 +014 Project.exe Graphics   6430  +1 TBitmap.SaveToStream
004ce75c +03c Project.exe GR32       4405  +4 TBitmap32.SaveToStream

Comment: Yes, I'm moving, dragging, clicking like a madman.

Comment: @NGLN: Anyway it just happens on my personal computer and on the sec one also with D7

Answer (score 4):

A guy from Graphics32 group found a solution for me. We have to amend some fixes to gr32 unit, as follows:

```
1) In TBitmap32.AssignTo() replace

  DrawTo(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0);

with

  Bmp.Canvas.Lock;
  try
    DrawTo(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0);
  finally
    Bmp.Canvas.UnLock;
  end;

2) In TBitmap32.Assign() replace

  TGraphicAccess(Source).Draw(Canvas, MakeRect(0, 0, Width, Height));

with

  Canvas.Lock;
  try
    TGraphicAccess(Source).Draw(Canvas, MakeRect(0, 0, Width, Height));
  finally
    Canvas.UnLock;
  end;

Now it works!
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure, please vote me down if I'm delusional.

TThreadSafeJpegImage.Draw locks the Canvas.
When moving the mouse across the form you force a redraw, which the form cannot do (because you've already locked the canvas previously) and this causes the error to be returned.

Change the Draw code like so:

```
procedure TThreadSafeJpegImage.Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect);
var
  OKToDraw: boolean;
begin 
  OKToDraw:= Bitmap.Canvas.TryLock;
  if OKTODraw then try
    inherited Draw(ACanvas, Rect);
  finally
    Bitmap.Canvas.Unlock;
  end; {if try}
end;
```

Comment: TThreadSafeJpegImage class doesn't matter in this situation. It is just mine replacement of the standard TJpegImage which makes this class thread-safe. With tjpegimage or mine TThreadSafeJpegImage I get this error in except block. Have you reproduced this error?

Comment: Bitmap is the internal bitmap of the jpeg unit, not the form :)

Comment: @John, 1. this a slight edit of a copy/paste of your code, you do see that right 2. Have **you** tested this? 3. Does it work? A simple copy/paste and run should tell you the answer. 4. There is no reference to a Form in this code.

Comment: Yes it does work(there are no more lines of code in the unit), there is no connection to the form. Just moving the cursor causes an error to be raised on the line: bmp32.SaveToStream(strStr);

Comment: @John, the A JpegImage does not have a Windows Handle, so it is the form that drives the drawing of the image, because the Image never receives the wm_paint message, the form does and calls the (inherited) draw of the jpegimage.